# How to emulate "Server closed connection without any data" with Fiddler?

Tags: request, client, httpresponse, fiddler, auto-responder

How to setup Fiddler to make next steps to reproduce:

1. Client sending HTTP (no matter what exactly) response to server
2. Server wait some time (emulate latency). For example, 50-100 ms as in real request.
3. Server closed connection without any data sent.

I tried play with AutoResponder but didn't find anything there :(

Much closer result which i find: create Empty.dat without data inside and send it as response in AutoReponder. But in this case Fiddler also send some data - auto generated headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK with automatic headers
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 12:21:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy, therefore even if the server does not respond the client gets the error from the proxy. And just closing the connection from within Fiddler is AFAIK not possible, as you don't have access to the connection, only to the request and response objects.

Comment: @Robert not pure proxy, as i understand it more complex. today i tried to set empty file as response but not helps... (added info to question)